# Wrong type argument: (or eieio-object-p class-p) semantic-bookmark-ring

Tags: emacs, cedet

I am using *Emacs 23* and *cedet 1.0.1*.

When I configured auto-complete in my .emacs file I am getting the error below whenever I am trying to open or save .c file from Emacs. It is hanging for a long time then throwing this error in *Messages* buffer. There is also a long sequence `Saving file <file path> and Wrote <file path>` lines in the buffer.

> if: Wrong type argument: (or eieio-object-p class-p), [object semantic-bookmark-ring "Ring" (0 3 . [[object semantic-bookmark "ac-config-default" ("ac-config-default" code nil nil [12669 12688]) nil 20 "/home/santanu/.emacs" 1 mark] [object semantic-bookmark "main" ("main" function (:arguments (("argc" variable (:type "int") (reparse-symbol arg-sub-list) #<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c>) ("argv" variable (:pointer 1 :dereference 1 :type "char") (reparse-symbol arg-sub-list) #<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c>)) :type "int") (unlink-copy-hook (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays) link-hook (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays) secondary-overlays (#<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c> #<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c> #<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c>) unlink-hook (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays)) #<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c>) nil 0 "/host/santanu/programming/c_projects/datastructures/src/main/hello.c" 1 edit] [object semantic-bookmark "stdio.h" ("stdio.h" include (:system-flag t) (unlink-hook (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays) secondary-overlays (#<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c>) dependency-file "/usr/include/stdio.h" link-hook (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays) unlink-copy-hook (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays) ...) #<overlay from 1 to 1 in hello.c>) nil 0 "/host/santanu/programming/c_projects/datastructures/src/main/hello.c" 1 mark] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...]) 0]
> To Remove Middle Tag: (main)
> Mark set
> To Remove Middle Tag: (main) [2 times]

**EDIT**: A new update on the issue

Accidentally I found the issue is not due to auto-complete. It is due to one Elisp function I wrote to apply Astyle of my C code before save. Here is the function and my c-mode-hook:

```
(defun astyle-this-buffer (pmin pmax)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region pmin pmax
                           "astyle" ;; add options here...
                           (current-buffer) t 
                           (get-buffer-create "*Astyle Errors*") t))

(defun ansi-c-mode-hook ()
  "turns off syntactic indentation and sets indent-region-function"
  (setq c-syntactic-indentation nil)
  ;;(setq indent-region-function 'astyle-this-buffer)
  (setq compile-command "bash cbuild.c")
  (setq enable-local-variables :all)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c .te") '(lambda ()
                                      (interactive)
                                      (run-command 'test-command)))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c .cs") '(lambda ()
                                      (interactive)
                                      (run-command 'check-code-style))))
```

If I uncomment the line `(setq indent-region-function 'astyle-this-buffer)` it is giving the above error on save. So what is the problem with the function `astyle-this-buffer`?

Comment: Can you `(setq debug-on-error t)` and post the resulting backtrace?  The error message does not seem correctly transcribed; or in any event, it is near impossible to make any sense of.

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade to current Emacs?

Comment: At present upgrade to recent version of Emacs is not an option. I shall execute `setq` and post the resulting backtrace.

Comment: I have checked by changing `(interactive "r")` to just `(interactive)` but without any improvement. I am very new to elisp so having difficulty in solving this.

Comment: `M-x debug-on-entry RET astyle-this-buffer RET`, then step through the function in the debugger using `d` (and `c` to skip through steps you don't care to look at). The first time you try it, just hit `c`, to see if the function ends OK and, if so, continue (`d`) from there. You can use binary search (judicious choice of `c` over `d`) or you can just drone through the details using `d d d ...`.